# std::is_default_constructible<T> error, if constructor is private

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I have following snippet

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

class C { C() { } };

int main()
{
   static_assert(!boost::has_trivial_default_constructor<C>::value, "Constructible");
   static_assert(!std::is_default_constructible<C>::value, "Constructible");
}
```

Conditions are not equal, but first condition works fine and second construction give error, that constructor is private. Compiler gcc 4.7... So, is this gcc bug, or it's defined by standard?

http://liveworkspace.org/code/NDQyMD$5

OK. Since this conditions are really unequal - we can use something like this

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

class C { private: C() noexcept(false) { } };

int main()
{
   static_assert(!boost::has_nothrow_constructor<C>::value, "Constructible");
   static_assert(!std::is_nothrow_constructible<C>::value, "Constructible");
}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/NDQyMD$24

Anyway, i know, that static_assert should not fails, since types are really not default constructible/not nothrow constructible. **Question is: WHY there is compilation error, not by my static assert?**

Comment: I see what you mean now. It looks like a bug then.

Comment: Note that the two traits inspect different properties.

Comment: @Xeo ok... and how about `has_nothrow_constructor` and `is_nothrow_constructible`?

Comment: Using a snaphot of the upcoming GCC 4.8 neither snippet results in an error and the result is as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a compiler bug. Let's see the following example of SFINAE(similar implementation is used in `g++`'s `type_traits` header)

```
#include <type_traits>

class Private
{
    Private()
    {

    }
};

class Delete
{
    Delete() = delete;
};

struct is_default_constructible_impl
{
    template<typename T, typename = decltype(T())>
    static std::true_type test(int);

    template<typename>
    static std::false_type test(...);
};

template <class T>
struct is_default_constructible: decltype(is_default_constructible_impl::test<T>(0))
{

};

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_default_constructible<Private>::value, "Private is not constructible");
    static_assert(is_default_constructible<Delete>::value, "Delete is not constructible");
}
```

The second assert works as expected, we can't deduce `Delete` type, since the class has only one deleted constructor. But when compiler tries to deduce type of `Private()`, it gives error: `Private::Private() is private`.  So, we have two classes with private constructor, but one of them gives error, and second - not. I think, that this behavior is wrong, but I can't find confirmation in the standard.

P.S. all off presented codes compiles by clang without any errors.

Comment: I don’t get it … `Private` is simply *not* default constructible, is it? Yes, it has a default constructor but of course that is unusable in the context of `is_default_constructible_impl::test` so the assertion fails, and I think that this implementation of the trait is entirely correct. – But to be honest the standard doesn’t seem to mention explicitly in §20.9.4.3 whether the constructors are supposed to be public or not; I just think that it makes way more sense to require this.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I incorrectly explained. Compilation fails when compiler tries to deduce type of `Private()`, not by static assert. Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The assertion doesn't fail. `std::is_constructible` itself fails. The standard does require the constructor to be public (in §20.9.4.3/6) but I don't think it means the type trait should cause a compiling error.

Comment: Thanks. Good answer. Now i tested std::is_default_constructible on MSVC 2012... And it works, but asserts and says, that type is constructible (so MSVC doesn't look on accessibility of construtor).

Comment: @soon Ah, that changes it. Yes, now I get your answer, and you are indeed correct, as far as I see.