# Why is_default_constructible<Class>::value fails within the same class scope

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, default-constructor, static-assert

Following works fine:

```
struct X { };  // OK
static_assert(std::is_default_constructible<X>::value, "Error");
```

Following assert fails to compile:

```
struct X { static_assert(std::is_default_constructible<X>::value, "Error"); };  // Fails
```

Why does the `static_assert` inside the class fail?

---

**Side Qn**: Is `std::is_default_constructible` supposed to fail for the classes with `private` constructors as discussed in:
[std::is_default_constructible<T> error, if constructor is private](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14030070/514235)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [documentation page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible) says that for `std::is_default_constructible<T>`:

> T shall be a complete type, (possibly cv-qualified) void, or an array of unknown bound. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Since you are within your class, the type is not completely defined yet, i guess that's the reason for the difference.

---

As for the side question, this trait seems to be based on [`std::is_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) which seems to mean that if the variable definition

```
T obj();
```

is [*well formed*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25335467/1147772) the member constant `value` equal to `true`. In all other cases, `value` is `false`.

So my understanding of this and my candid name based semantical instinct would say that it should fail if the default constructor is private.

Comment: The workaround for this situation is to enclose this `static_assert` inside some member method of that class. Is there any reference from standard as well? BTW, what is the meaning of *"array of unknown bound"*? -- You can also respond on the "Side Qn" for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @iammilind Updated with side question answer, also an array of unknown bound is when you don't put a number between the brackets -> `char array[];`. Most of the time cppreference quotes/rephrase the standard, but yeah you should always check the original source for safety, i don't have an accessible copy of it right now though.